# picklist options change depending on previous picklist

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist, global-picklist

I have a requirement to have 2 picklists. The user should select an option in Picklist 1, and based upon their selection Picklist 2 will only display certain specific options. These options should change depending on what is selected in Picklist 1. How can I go about accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is built-in functionality via [Dependent Picklists](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&type=5).

To use the terminology in the documentation, Picklist 1 would be your controlling field, and Picklist 2 would be your dependent picklist.

Answer (score 0):

That is an in-build out of the box Salespforce feature.

Here is how it works:

[Dependant Picklists - Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_dependent_fields.htm)